# I want to use SQL Server reporting service in Windows application on .NET?

Tags: reportingservices-2005

i am new in ssrs i want some sugeestiion from You can i use ssrs in windows application in .net if yes then please tell me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964126%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: please give a example for ssrs in  windows application